# Contenteditable block inside link, how to prevent redirect but let text selection\caret position changes?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, contenteditable, event-bubbling

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qh7Sq/

I want to be able edit span inside link, actually I could by some part of preventing bubbling propagation blocks caret change action.

Please don't suggest different markup, only javascript.

Comment: I tried your link. I am able to edit the span inside the link without any issues. What exactly you need in this? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's going to be a nice way of doing this without making the whole link editable:

```
$('a').prop("contentEditable", "true");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qh7Sq/1/

Comment: @Viller: The only other options I can think of are very hacky.

Comment: not actually, Ive already worked around by removing href attribute for the editing time. But it's not elegant. I just cannot find when in the event bubbling chain redirection triggers, so I could prevent only this event

Comment: @Viller: Does that work in every browser? I didn't suggest it because I had a vague idea that some browser wouldn't display content inside an `<a>` element with no attributes, but I could well be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it:

1. prevent click-default inside contenteditables
2. and for firefox, remove and add href-attribute to prevent placing the cursor at the start of the contenteditable-element

https://jsfiddle.net/e15j8oq9/1/

```js
// if contenteditable inside a link
document.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    if (e.button !== 0) return;
    if (e.target.isContentEditable) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (e.explicitOriginalTarget && e.explicitOriginalTarget.isContentEditable) { // keyboard click firefox
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

// prevent (Firefox) placing cursor incorrectly
document.addEventListener('mousedown', e=>{
    if (!e.target.isContentEditable) return;
    var link = e.target.closest('a');
    if (link) {
        const href = link.getAttribute('href')
        link.removeAttribute('href');
        setTimeout(()=>link.setAttribute('href', href))
    }
});
```